# Conditional Order by based on aggregate value of a column in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has ID, CW_savings, PW_Savings and Savings_Diff(CW-PW). I want to order the table depending on the sum(Savings_Diff), if it is >=0 then Desc(greatest positive diff shown first) else asc(greatest -ve diff shown first). Currently i am using :

```
select ID, CW_savings, PW_Savings,Savings_Diff
from table 
order by case 
  when sum(savings_diff) >=0 then Savings_diff end DESC
  when sum(savings_diff) < 0 then SAvings_diff end ASC
;
```

This query is not working because i believe you can't use aggregate functions in Order by clause.
Looking for a workaround on this?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, in the wanted order. (As formatted text, no images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sum that you want to check is the total sum of the column `Savings_Diff` of all the rows of the table then you can do this:

```
select t.ID, t.CW_savings, t.PW_Savings, t.Savings_Diff
from tablename t 
cross join (select sum(Savings_Diff) total from table) s   
order by -sign(s.total) * t.Savings_diff
```

When the sum is positive then the sorting is equivalent to:

```
order by -Savings_diff
```

or

```
order by Savings_diff DESC
```

When the sum is negative then the sorting is equivalent to:

```
order by Savings_diff
```

or

```
order by Savings_diff ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to speculate that `id` has multiple rows in the table and you want the sum for the `id`.  You can use window functions:

```
select ID, CW_savings, PW_Savings,Savings_Diff
from table 
order by (case when sum(savings_diff) over (partition by id) >= 0 then Savings_diff end) desc,
         (case when sum(savings_diff) over (partition by id) < 0 then savings_diff end) ASC;
```

Comment: Umm no. I want to get the top 10 IDs with the above conditions not to find sum for each ID.